# Deploying WAR with multi-version jar fails

Tags: maven, jar, war, apache-tomee

I am currently constrained to JDK17.  I build with maven and a dependency requires a further jar of jackson 2.15.0 which jar is a multi-release with versions for Java 11, 17 and 19.  I am building a WAR file but when deploying to a (webprofile) server (TomEE 9.1.1, Glassfish v6.2.5), deployment fails with errors such as:

> Exception while visiting
> META-INF/versions/19/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/io/doubleparser/FastIntegerMath.class
> of size 5112 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class
> file major version 63

63 is Java 19, of course.

Glassfish 7.0.1 on the other hand, works, albeit it being very slow deploying (on localhost).

I read that modern servers can deal with MRjars (eg: latest jetty, glassfish etc.). I couldn't find any maven property (compiler source/target/release), exclude or enforcer (eg: requireJavaVersion) which worked so how do I successfully deploy my WAR on to my remote TomEE (if at all possible)?

Comment: The problem is related to your server ...Glassfish .. which means it does not handle multi release jars correct... in such cases the server should ignore things `META-INF/versions/..`...Also that can not be solved by the build (Maven) because the server accessing it during the deployment... which is the issue...What do you mean by enforcer? That is for build time not for runtime...?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try if explicitly adding the dependency with provided scope works? It marks that the dependency should be provided by the container, therefore the server would use its own version which should work.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Which leads into the issue that the server is using an old versions which has security issues... ?

Comment: @khmarbaise could be, but that is to be solved by the server admin (upgrades maybe), not by the app developer, right?

Comment: Excellent thanks!  That works.

Comment: Not the server admin it's by the provider of the app server ... that's an old issue with application kind of servers... they all contain libs which are not easily even if updatable .. That's the reason why you should package everying yourself ... and that's also a reason to go aways from such setups.. The update cycles of such old models are simply not fast enough...